# Using gson to converting an object works but causes strange memory error and crash

Tags: android, eclipse, gson

I have a code  that is in an view started by an activity

```
Object object=new Object();//It holds other objects,arraylist,arrays vs..
Gson gson=new Gson();
String json=gson.toJson(object);
object=(Object) gson.fromJson(json, Objectclass);
```

When i start the activity and show view it works. But after Quit by pressing back button and enter again it crashes. The crash has something to do with memory because if i dont load a bitmap for example the crash happens after  a couple try.

Here is the error log

```
01-29 17:48:41.037: D/dalvikvm(9978): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 824K, 7% free 11909K/12772K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): FATAL ERROR occurring at line: 4858
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): least_addr: 0x40039000, mchunkptr: 0x635d9bb8. Segment Infomation:
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):       base    :  size
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   000 62927000:  40960
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   001 627b5000:  32768
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   002 6364e000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   003 63623000:  167936
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   004 635d3000:  77824
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   005 635c0000:  73728
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   006 635b7000:  32768
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   007 635a9000:  53248
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   008 63464000:  212992
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   009 636c4000:  163840
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   010 636c0000:  8192
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   011 636bd000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   012 63699000:  40960
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   013 63692000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   014 63696000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   015 63686000:  49152
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   016 6323b000:  163840
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   017 63233000:  32768
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   018 62b85000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   019 627e9000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   020 627ad000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   021 6269a000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   022 5d1cb000:  40960
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   023 5d19b000:  36864
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   024 5d18c000:  45056
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   025 5d16f000:  16384
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   026 5d162000:  49152
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   027 5d14b000:  28672
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   028 5d146000:  8192
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   029 5d13e000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   030 5d136000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   031 5d127000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   032 5d11f000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   033 5cecf000:  229376
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   034 61385000:  20480
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   035 5d265000:  40960
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   036 61357000:  188416
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   037 60100000:  196608
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   038 5e4d2000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   039 5e48e000:  69632
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   040 6001d000:  86016
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   041 60005000:  28672
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   042 5e4af000:  143360
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   043 5dbbd000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   044 5e4ac000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   045 5e48a000:  16384
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   046 5dc33000:  94208
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   047 5dbf4000:  94208
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   048 5dc11000:  20480
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   049 5dbb9000:  16384
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   050 5d1f7000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   051 5d274000:  188416
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   052 5d25c000:  36864
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   053 5d1e6000:  69632
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   054 5bc3e000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   055 5d1de000:  32768
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   056 5b504000:  57344
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   057 5a44a000:  32768
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   058 5a445000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   059 5a43b000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   060 5a057000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   061 5a044000:  20480
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   062 5903f000:  20480
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   063 59036000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   064 430d9000:  24576
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   065 430d5000:  12288
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   066 40039000:  4096
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): chunk ptr 0x635d9bb8(p), cinuse(1), pinuse(0), chunksize(96)
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9bb8:  00000060  prev_foot
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9bbc:  00000062  head
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9bc0:  00000000  fd
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9bc4:  41400000  bk
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): chunk ptr p->fd is invalid with any segment
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): chunk ptr p->bk is invalid with any segment
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): chunk ptr 0x635d9b58(prev), cinuse(0), pinuse(0), chunksize(288)
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b58:  00000000  prev_foot
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b5c:  00000120  head
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b60:  635d9b58  fd
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b64:  635d9b58  bk
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b68:  00000000  child[0]
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b6c:  00000000  child[1]
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9b70:  635e4c68  parent
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** HEAP INFO *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): chunk ptr 0x635d9c18(next), cinuse(1), pinuse(0), chunksize(96)
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9c18:  000000c0  prev_foot
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9c1c:  00000062  head
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9c20:  00000000  fd
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978):   635d9c24:  42480000  bk
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x635d9bb8 passed to dlfree
01-29 17:48:41.047: A/libc(9978): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 9987 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

Comment: You asked this question a long time ago. Did you finally find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Nope, I did not

Comment: I've never seen crash reports like this developing android applications. From where is it coming from? Do I understand it correctly that you are using eclipse, but not Android Studio?

Comment: I have no idea but i don't think this was ecplise. Maybe some other platform that builds for multiple OS.